# How to Change header background on react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

i'm new to react and try to make dynamic change background of header base on router path where i am. I don't wanna use redux.

I try to implement **withrouter**, but without success. The hard part for me  to understand is how to change a class of a component outside the Route. In my case i have to change  to a specific class.

```
<Menu className="White"/> // <- wanna change this className="" based on the route
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> // <- this should have White className menu  <Menu className="white" />
<Route exact path="/lala" component={lala} /> // <- this should have Black className menu <Menu className="black" />
</Switch>
```

I expect that when i change route, my Menu(Header) color change.

Comment: what happened when you used withRouter?

Comment: i just don't understand how to use it to change className for my <Menu /> component.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Chief give me this easy solution:

```
import * as cn from 'classnames' 

    const Menu: React.FC<Props> = ({className, children, authenticated, handleAuthentication, location}) => {
        function isHome() {
            return location.pathname === '/' ? true : false;
        }

        return(
                <div className={cn('mydefaultclass', {'bgwhite': !isHome()}, className)}>
//etc
)}
```

And in my App.tsx i just keep my routes without any changes. So in this case my home should have transparent bg so take the default class, and when i go in other path my bg become white.

So i add just this logic

```
 function isHome() {
                return location.pathname === '/' ? true : false;
            }
```

and this

```
{'bgwhite': !isHome()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass props from route to component as,

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
<Home cls="white">}} />
<Route exact path="/lala" render={() => {
<lala cls="black">}} />
</Switch>
```

Then in your component you can use this,

```
<Menu className={this.props.cls}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you try something like:

```
function MenuComponent(props) {
  const [className, setClassName] = useState("white")

  useEffect(function() {
    setClassName(props.match.path === "/lala" ? "yellow" : "white")
  }, [props.match.path])

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      ...etc
    </div>
  )
}

export const Menu = withRouter(MenuComponent)
```

`withRouter` is something you can wrap a component in and the wrapped component will receive all of the router props such as match and history. You can then check if the path changes during an effect or something like `componentDidUpdate` and then update the class of the component accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, i know this is correct, but i still have problem to integrate this in my already existing component  Menu.tsx ``` const Menu: React.FC<Props> = ({className, children, authenticated, handleAuthentication}) => { ... } ``` i'm a little confused and i must use typescript too so not make my work easier .. or i should use this function in my App.tsx file?

Answer (score -1):

You can render Menu using

```
<Route component={Menu} />
```

But you will need to move the styling to inside the menu component.

This will give the menu component the router props so you can check the `location` and style it how you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a checker something like:

```
const currentUrl= window.location.href

const clsColor=
 if(currentUrl.contains('/url-1'){ //or .includes()
    return: 'red'
  }else if(currentUrl.contains('/url-2')
    return: 'white'
  }else{
    return: 'default-color'
  }
// you can also use a cslColor = currentUrl.includes('/url-3') ? 'red' : 'white'
```